# Does replaceChild break childNodes iteration in Python minidom DOM implementation?

Tags: python, dom, minidom

Does `replaceChild()` break `for` loop around `childNodes` in Python minidom?

Consider the following code with `v` being a minidom node:

```
    for w in v.childNodes:
        if ...:
            frag = parseString(...)
            v.replaceChild(w, frag.documentElement)
```

Will it work as expected enumerating all child nodes in turn? Or will `replaceChild` break the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html says:

> The content of the returned NodeList is "live" in the sense that, for
>   instance, changes to the children of the node object that it  was
>   created from are immediately reflected in the nodes returned by the
>   NodeList accessors; it is not a static snapshot of the content of the
>   node.

This follows that the loop won't be broken.

Comment: However Python docs say: `NodeList objects are implemented using Python’s built-in list type.` It seems to hint that the lists are not really "live". However for my particular task `list` object would do the right thing, anyway